# How to display images from a network using PHP

Tags: php

I have a local intranet webpage hosted @ let's say, 192.168.20.1, and I have a bunch of images and videos @ 192.168.20.5

Is it possible to display those images/videos using  and  tags using PHP?

What I did before is to make a temporary copy of those network files in the webserver and then display it but some of the files, especially, the videos are too large and consumes a lot of time copying...

Is this possible in PHP?  Thanks in advance

Also, the network folder has credentials (username/password)... thanks

Comment: Is media server is accessible using web browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the IP address in the tags, for example:

```
<?php $otherServer = 'http://192.168.20.5'; ?>

<img src="<?php echo $otherServer ?>/images/image1.jpg">
```

Using a variable will make it much easier to maintain the code.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there's also a need to include credentials, username and password for the network folder

Comment: My bad, the sample files I'm trying to load is not supported... This method works thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You can build some PHP APIS in media host with Authentication functionary and return media file URL directly. And the credentials can hold in cookies when loggin.